# How do I upload my arff file to WEKA without seeing 'premature end of line, read Token[EOL] line 22'

Tags: dataset, data-science, weka, arff

This error message has been appearing when I try to upload a dataset I got from twitter using snscrape:

'premature end of line, read Token[EOL] line 22'

How do I resolve it?

I've tried to convert the file, it keeps showing the same error.
I downloaded the file in JSON and CSV, tried using it in WEKA, the same thing still happens.

[file not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvJpQ.png).

Comment: Post the start of your ARFF file, up to line 23. If you didn't use the Weka API to generate the file then you may have incorrect quoting, hence ending up with unexpected EOL.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was that WEKA was seeing multiple commas and only 2 column headers in the csv file.**

I eventually resolved it by opening the csv file in Excel and using find and replace to remove all the commas that was affecting the shape of the csv. Resaved the file and tried again.

Thanks!